# Installing a SSIS package. Slightly confused

Tags: ssis

Ok - this is probably a silly question but what the hell.

I've created a SSIS package with configuration and a deployment manifest. When I copied this over to the server and double clicked it, the Package Wizard returned an error - that Integration Services wasn't installed - bad.

But when I did an export data task via SSMS, I noticed I could save this task as a package. When I set up a job I noticed I could actually select an SSIS package to schedule - even though SSIS is not installed(!?!) Does this mean I could just point to my earlier package and schedule that?

If so, do you only need Integration Services installed in order to install packages within SQL Server - its fine to run them from the file system?

Cheers

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you trying to run the package on? Keep in mind SSIS is only available on Standard and Enterprise. So if you're running Express you're out of luck. Also, AFAIK, the tools to create a job within SQL Agent have no knowledge of whether SSIS exists. So you can set up a job and tell the agent to execute a package even if you don't have SSIS. Of course, you'll run into the same error when the task actually executes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article on different ways to execute a package programmatically:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michen/archive/2007/03/22/running-ssis-package-programmatically.aspx